Is there a way to calculate lcm of at most 30 numbers with each number being largest at 10^6?
I'm using C++ for this. The problem is that the answer can't be a long long, because the number is gigantically big, like 10^50. With this type of problem, I really can't think of any solutions.
If you can help, I will be very grateful!

Decompose each number into its prime factors. You can then simply take the point-wise maximum of both prime factor sets.

Yeah, but it does fit into three 64-bit numbers. That's not even close to being "big" tbh. You can use some bigint lib.

Hint:  look up the relationship between LCM (least common multiple) and HCF (highest common factor) of two numbers.

As the exponents in each of the prime factors 2^m.3^n.5^p.7^q.11^r.random_prime1.etc. If you want native support for multiprecision arithmetic it is best to use a language that supports it. I prefer @Botje 's suggestion and then you can multiply it up in eg Julia.

I'd never heard of bigint! Thank you freakish. Now I will have trouble learning it!

Are you sure about the result being smaller than 10^50? If all 30 numbers are primes close to 10^6, you will end up with a number in the range of 10^180.

@AnhTríHoàng well, the alternative is to do it manually. Try this: https://github.com/rgroshanrg/bigint Doesn't look too difficult. In fact the lib overloads most standard operators, and so it feels like working with normal numbers. Of course every such lib will be significantly slower than "small int" arithmetic. But you cannot avoid some performance hit anyway.

Btw: there is no known polynomial algorithm for integer factorization. Meaning this idea is not only complex to implement, but also will be very slow. Although 10^6 is probably still managable. Either way I would avoid it.

If you have an algorithm that calculates that "lcm" thing, I'd just start with something like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html (since I generally use a lot of boost anyway, and their cpp_int has arbitrary size) to get the large numbers handled.

Try the list [999983, 999979, 999961, 999959, 999953, 999931, 999917, 999907, 999883, 999863, 999853, 999809, 999773, 999769, 999763, 999749, 999727, 999721, 999683, 999671, 999667, 999653, 999631, 999623, 999613, 999611, 999599, 999563, 999553, 999541]. I believe (but it could do with checking) that the LCM is
992931959114478637982633866590412594309972343006795969489241936432454753555915395748818499173315964528042642599831559088748955006653902078860496826816983588915413262059190869117223

You need a Big Number library. You can implement a simplistic version using std::vector or use pre-existing 3rd party; boost.multiprecision provides 3 implementations. But there are others too.

Is this a homework project? Is the intended learning outcome that you use a bigint library or write a bigint library?

Problem
You have a finite set of numbers of which you intend to compute the lowest common multiplier of. We will see the algorithm and some technical problems. I will mostly use pseudo-code so we will have a clear idea of what needs to be implemented.
Definition
Lowest Common Multiplier(x1, x2, ..., xn) = X where X mod xi === 0 where 1 <= i <= n
Not technical algorithm
lcm <- x1
for (i <- 2 to n)
    lcm <- compute_lcm(lcm, xi)
end for

where compute_lcm computes the lcm of two numbers, by decomposing them into products of primes and computing the product of the union of common primes, for example
lcm(12, 18) is 36, because 12 = 2^2 * 3^1 and 36 = 2^1 * 3^2, so the prime union in this case is 2^2 * 3^2 = 36
A more technical and optimal approach
The components we need for this solution is:

prime decomposition (I recommend the use of map<T1,T1> where the key is the prime and the value is the power this prime is raised to and of course, T1 and T2 are the types of your choice, be it int, long, whatever)
prime union computation
unifying decompositions

Prime Decomposition
Every natural number can be decomposed into primes of whose product, with each prime raised to the correct power yields the number, so it is of the form of
x1^y1 * x2^y2 * ... * xn^yn
where xi is the i'th prime and yi is the i'th power
Algorithmically decomposing a number looks like this:
while (n != 1)
    p <- next_prime(p)
    counter <- 0;
    while !(n % p)
        counter <- counter + 1
        n <- n / p
    end while
    if (counter > 1) map[p] <- counter
end while

Prime Union computation
If you already have two maps of whose union you want to compute where m1 and m2 are your maps, then

create an empty m3
loop m1 current representing the current element

if m2.find(current->first) == m2.end() then m3[current->first] = current->second
else m3[current->first] = max(current->second, m2[current=>first])


loop m2 current being the current element

if m1.find(current->first) == m1.end() then m3[current->first] = current->second



Decompose and unify
It is worth to implement a decompose and a unify method as described earlier, because then you can do something like this:
mymap = decompose(x[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    mymap = unify(mymap, decompose(x[i]));
}

Technicalities
Surely, if you may have 30 numbers from whose the largest values could be 1 000 000, then the biggest prime below a million is 999 983. This will require roughly 10^180, which goes beyond the limits of long long, even if you win a bit with unsigned.
So, to achieve your goal, you may consider representing your number as a collection of digits (which could be a vector, for example) in the number-base of your choice. d[0] representing the first digit (from right), d[1] representing the second and so on.
You can create a class for your thusly defined numbers and operators for this class. You will need operators for

*
/
%

and define your map<int, LargeNumber>, because your primes will be less than a million and they fit in to an int, whereas the products you are computing will be of LargeNumber.
A tip is to first try and use a base of 10 until it works correctly, then you may change your number base to something bigger (like a number base of a million).

One of the fastest way to achieve this is through the following steps:

Use some bigint library, i.e. a library that handles numbers of arbitrary size. One such library is this one: https://github.com/rgroshanrg/bigint Note that every such library will be significantly slower than using small ints. This kind of libraries treats arbitrary sequence of bytes as base-256 number.
Utilize lcm(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=lcm(x_1, lxm(x_2,...,x_n)) formula.
Utilize lcm(x,y)=xy/gcd(x,y) formula. Thanks to bigint library we don't have to worry about xy going too big. In your particular case the upper bound is 10^180, and so you should fit in ~75 bytes. Not necessarily a big deal (depending on concrete requirements).
Implement efficient gcd(x,y), e.g. the Euclidean algorithm.


Well, one approach is:

Find the prime numbers less than 1000000. (I'd advocate using a sieve for this.)

For each number that you have, write its prime factorisation using powers of these primes p, q, r, ...:


x=paqbrc...

Collect the maximum power of each of these primes over all your numbers, so that the LCM can be written

x=pAqBrC...

Each of those prime powers, pA etc., is less than 1000000, so you are then left with multiplying a set of modest numbers together. Whilst you could use a BigInt library, you only really need (a) a container for the digits (string or vector will do) and (b) a single multiplication operation, which you call repeatedly, and could be done by the sort of multiply-and-carry operation taught at primary school. (Or you could use Python, as I did for a comment).

Are you sure that you are telling us the whole question, though? You didn't want an answer modulo something, for example?
